# How to reset Data Sense statistics?

Tags: datasense

Is there a way to drop all collected statistics to zero? Is this possible using Data Sense app or any system settings?

Comment: I think this is possible only with reset (maybe a SIM card change too). Can I ask why you need it? ;)

Comment: Set your Limit type to Monthly then set the Reset Date at today?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might not be the prettiest of solutions, but it worked for me.

1. Open settings and scroll down to **date+time**
2. Change date to one year ahead of now (so 2015 since it's 2014 now)
3. Press done to accept the change
4. Open the data sense app and wait for it to fully load (it should say that you've used nothing) (if data sense get stuck on loading, you can close it by holding down the back button and using the **X** at the top right corner)
5. Close data sense, go back to settings and change the date back (in my case 2014)
6. Open data sense again and you should notice that all the data is gone

PS. This worked for me but can't guarantee it will work for you .DS
PSS. If it doesn't work you might want to try to use the same data sense settings as me:
Limit type: Montly
Montly reset date: 1
Data limit: 3
Units: GB
.DSS

Got the idea from "**Gaurav Paul**" at this [thread](http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-720/247267-data-sense-reset.html#post2193631) on the wpcentral forum

Comment: Changing the date by rolling forward a year worked for me. Thanks for the post

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to date and time settings
2. Adjust the time to nearly 12 AM
3. Go to Data Sense, settings, set a monthly limit and choose the next day from the current day
4. You will see it say "Your data will reset in 1 day"
5. Wait until 12 AM
6. Your data has been reset

Answer (score 1):

I just went to my provider website, checked my balance and added that amount to wathever the app showed. Then I adjusted the day of the month my bill would cycle and, that did it...
Just remember to go back to the app the day after your bill starts and set it to zero.